# React Native step of my function not respected

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this code, basically, in createRule, i'm posting something on a url, and i'm taking an ID from apiResponse. When createRule is finished, i'm taking the ID and i'm going in another component to use this ID. But my problem is, i'm going in the component before the end of my fetch, and i don't know why

```
  select_action(value) {
      this.createRule("gitlab", '0')

      console.log("last step: ")
      console.log(localStorage.getItem('id'))
      this.state.data.push({id:Math.floor(Math.random() * 50000) + 1 , component:<Other/>
    })
  }


  createRule = (service, action) => {
    let data = { 
      service_id: service,
      action_id: action
    }
    fetch(my_link, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
      .then((apiResponse)=>{
        console.log("first step: ")

        console.log(apiResponse.id)
        localStorage.setItem('id', apiResponse.id);    
      })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

And i have this with my logs

```
last step: 
80
first step: 
81
```

(The 80 is the id from my localStorage before my fetch).
Anyone know why my createRule is not the first thing to be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will need to await for the result from createRule func. Otherwise, it will always go to the next line, because it does not know that this needs to wait for the API call to be done.